# How do you call your module's controller function from an entirely separate module's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-module

I'm just getting to grips with Angular, but passing around scope is getting the better of me when I try to abstract reusable components into separate modules.

I'm using an Angular Youtube module found here https://github.com/arnaudbreton/angular-youtube but it's woefully inadequate so I'm bolting on new functionality, namely support for the youtube API's Events.

First, here's the pertinent snippet from the third party module (abridged):

```
angular.module('youtube', ['ng'])

    .service('youtubePlayerApi', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($window, $rootScope, $log) {
        var player = $rootScope.$new(true);

        player.playerContainer = null;

        player.create = function (attrs) {          
            player.playerId = attrs.id;
            player.videoId = attrs.videoId;

            return new YT.Player(this.playerId, {
                videoId: attrs.videoId,

                events:{
                    onStateChange: function(event){
                        switch(event.data){
                            case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                                attrs.onEvent()
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        player.load = function(){
            this.playerContainer = player.create();
        }

        return player;
    }])

    .directive('youtubePlayer', ['youtubePlayerApi', function (youtubePlayerApi) {
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            scope: {
                id:'@',
                videoId:'@',
                onEvent:'&'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                youtubePlayerApi.create(attrs);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Then there's my own module:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['youtube']);

myapp.controller('myAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$log', 'youtubePlayerApi', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $log, youtubePlayerApi) {

    $scope.showVideo = function(){
        $scope.youtubePlayer = youtubePlayerApi.load();
    }

    $scope.myEventHandler = function(){
        alert('finished!')
    }
}]);
```

and the associated template:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" id="ng-app">
    <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
        <div youtube-player id="ytplayer" video-id="0BWD5I6YrIo" on-event="myEventHandler()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you'll see I'm struggling to connect the `myeventhandler()` function of `myAppCtrl` with the `youtubeapi` module.

I'm also not sure I'm configuring the Isolate scope variables correctly as I've only ever seen it done when the scope values are being passed to a template, not a link function like this.

Any pointers on where i'm going wrong?

Comment: I haven't yet pulled this code into a test app and played with it, but to me it looks like you're doing everything right--the code for the YouTube stuff looks fishy to me. I notice the code on GitHub doesn't match the code here; you may want to try updating the angular-youtube code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isolate scope variables are configured correctly. `attrs.onEvent()` does not work because attributes are strings rather than expressions. Still, the directive can pass the event handler to the service using its isolate scope variable:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // using the isolate scope binding
    youtubePlayerApi.create(attrs, scope.onEvent); 
}
```

You would then modify `create` to accept the new parameter:

```
player.create = function (attrs, handler) {
```

And also within `create`, change `attrs.onEvent()` to `handler()`

Comment: Thanks guys, I had a suspicion I was almost there, it was all down to passing scope fo the handler.